# How Do I Merge An Array Var Into An Object-Array One?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a var object which is pulled to show events on a calendar.

This is an example of the var:

```
var myEvents = {'10-02-2013' : '<span>Event1</span>','10-04-2013' : '<span>Event2</span>','12-25-2013' : '<span>Christmas Day</span>','12-31-2013' : '<span>New Year\'s Eve</span>'};
```

Var myEvents outputs as

**Object {10-02-2013: "Event1", 10-04-2013: "Event2", 12-25-2013: "Christmas Day", 12-31-2013: "New Year's Eve"}**

Since i also have recurring events of the same kind, i create them on the fly like this:

```
var day = 4;
var date = new Date();
var nextYear = date.getFullYear() + 1;
var recurring = [];

while(date.getDay() != day)
{
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)    
}

while(date.getFullYear() < nextYear)
{
var yyyy = date.getFullYear();

var mm = (date.getMonth() + 1);
mm = (mm < 10) ? '0' + mm : mm;

var dd = date.getDate();
dd = (dd < 10) ? '0' + dd : dd;

var output = mm + '-' + dd + '-' + yyyy + ' : ' + '<span>Website Update</span>';
recurring.push(output);
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);
}
```

var recurring outputs as

**["10-03-2013 : Website Update", "10-10-2013 : Website Update", "10-17-2013 : Website Update", "10-24-2013 : Website Update", "10-31-2013 : Website Update", "11-07-2013 : Website Update", "11-14-2013 : Website Update", "11-21-2013 : Website Update", "11-28-2013 : Website Update", "12-05-2013 : Website Update", "12-12-2013 : Website Update", "12-19-2013 : Website Update", "12-26-2013 : Website Update"]**

I need to merge recurring into myEvents, so that when i pull myEvents i get

**Object {10-02-2013: "Event1", 10-04-2013: "Event2", 12-25-2013: "Christmas Day", 12-31-2013: "New Year's Eve", 10-03-2013: "Website Update", 10-10-2013: "Website Update", 10-17-2013: "Website Update", 10-24-2013: "Website Update", 10-31-2013: "Website Update", 11-07-2013: "Website Update", 11-14-2013: "Website Update", 11-21-2013: "Website Update", 11-28-2013: "Website Update", 12-05-2013: "Website Update", 12-12-2013: "Website Update", 12-19-2013: "Website Update", 12-26-2013: "Website Update"}**

I thought i could just get recurring as a string using

```
var recurring2 = recurring.join();
```

and then pass it to myEvents like

```
var myEvents = { recurring2 + ('10-02-2013' : '<span>Event1</span>','10-04-2013' : '<span>Event2</span>','12-25-2013' : '<span>Christmas Day</span>','12-31-2013' : '<span>New Year\'s Eve</span>')};
```

but yeah...i guess i was a fool. Moving my first steps with javascript, even after a long research i wasn't able to understand how to merge that array var into the object var that i need to pull. 
How can i achieve that?

Comment: Have you tried `$.grep()`?

Comment: $.grep just returns me both vars but still one as array and one as object, to my understanding. I don't get myEvents as object with content of recurring added to it.

Comment: I see. Was just a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
var day = 4;
var date = new Date();
var nextYear = date.getFullYear() + 1;
var recurring = {}; // Make recurring as new object instead of new Array.

while(date.getDay() != day) {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)    
}

while(date.getFullYear() < nextYear) {
    var yyyy = date.getFullYear();

    var mm = (date.getMonth() + 1);
    mm = (mm < 10) ? '0' + mm : mm;

    var dd = date.getDate();
    dd = (dd < 10) ? '0' + dd : dd;

    // Assign as a property of the object instead of an array.
    recurring['mm + '-' + dd + '-' + yyyy + '] = '<span>Website Update</span>';
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);
}

var myEvents = {'10-02-2013' : '<span>Event1</span>','10-04-2013' : '<span>Event2</span>','12-25-2013' : '<span>Christmas Day</span>','12-31-2013' : '<span>New Year\'s Eve</span>'};

//Finally merge two objects. so you can get one overall object as expected.
finalObject = $.extend({}, myEvents, recurring);
```

Comment: Thank you Ghanshyam. I'm getting a _$ is not defined_ error on the $.extend line?

Comment: As with Tibos answer, i only get the myEvents output, while the recurring does not get merged. I would show you on jsbin but your code returns a $ not defined error - http://jsbin.com/ObEDIWi/7/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Actually i just replaced `recurring['mm + '-' + dd + '-' + yyyy + ']` with `recurring[mm + '-' + dd + '-' + yyyy]` and it worked like a charm. Thanks for this solution which i'm going to accept.

Answer (score 0):

With the note that the keys of the object must be unique (so if you have two events on the same date, the second one will overwrite the first), you can do this:

Instead of (or in addition to):

```
var output = mm + '-' + dd + '-' + yyyy + ' : ' + '<span>Website Update</span>';
```

Do:

```
myEvents[mm + '-' + dd + '-' + yyyy] = '<span>Website Update</span>';
```

Your myEvents variable should hold a single object with dates as keys and events as values.

PS: If you need to use the recurring array, then you can do some string splitting (on your original version):

```
for (var i=0; i<recurring.length; i++) {
  var split = recurring[i].split(' : ');
  myEvents[split[0]] = split[1];
}
```

Demo for second version: http://jsbin.com/iSilaPO/1/edit

Comment: Thank you so much Tibos. Unfortunately, when applied to my code, it returns just the original myEvents var. Could it be a formatting problem on trhe recurring var loop? http://jsbin.com/ObEDIWi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: With a simple 5 second debug i can notice that the problem is the recurring array is empty after your code attempts to build it. The difference between your code here and your original version is that in the first one you correctly add items to the array using `push` and in the second you add properties to it as if it were a map (object), so they won't turn up when iterating using `for`.